# A question about <token2> in \expandafter<token1><token2>

Tags: plain-tex

I am getting confused about the `\expandafter` command in TeX. In TeXbook, Knuth said that

> **`\expandafter` *token*.** TeX first reads the token that comes immediately after
>   `\expandafter`, without expanding it; let's call this token *t*. Then TeX reads the token
>   that comes after *t* (and possibly more tokens, if that token has an argument), replacing
>   it by its expansion. Finally TeX puts *t* back in front of that expansion.

Here is an example:

```
% \b\c->\c->A
\def\a#1{\ifx#1\c c\else not c\fi}
\def\b#1{#1}
\def\c{A}
\expandafter\a\b\c
\bye
```

the result is `c`, not `not c`, which is not what I expect! Since TeX replace  (token that comes after *t*) by its expansion, why does `\c` not expand into letter `A`?
How should I understand `\expandafter`?

Comment: `\expandafter\a\b\c` will expand `\b` (once!) first which as it reads `\c` as its argument leads to `\a\c` (the expansion of `\b` is `\c`, not `A`) so `\a` gets `\c` as its argument and compares it to `\c` and consequently the result is `c`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expansion of `\b` consists in looking for an argument and substituting `\b` and the argument with the replacement text. So when the `\expandafter` acts, it does its job and disappears, leaving

```
\a\c
```

in the input stream. This in turn expands to

```
\ifx\c\c c\else not c\fi
```

which correctly gives `c`. If you want to expand also the `\c` token you have to do differently:

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\a\b\c
```

When the first `\expandafter` acts you remain with

```
\expandafter\a\c
```

and then the action of the left `\expandafter` will produce

```
\a A
```

which becomes

```
\ifx A\c c\else not c\fi
```

that will give `not c`.

Remember that `\expandafter` does only the *first level expansion*, not all the way through.